# Perform calculation for table column in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, oop

So basically I am trying to do a shopping cart. I need to update the product amount if a transaction is successful. I use an array list and for loop to loop thru the items in my cart:

```
ArrayList<shopManagement.entity.Cart> ft = cart.getCartItems();
        for (int count = 0; count < ft.size(); count++) {
            int quantity = ft.get(count).getQuantity();
            int prodID = ft.get(count).getProdID();
            shopManagement.entity.Cart cart3 = new shopManagement.entity.Cart(quantity, prodID);
            boolean success = cart3.updateProdQuantity();
        }
```

I get the quantity bought of each product. Then after that, I need to use the quantity variable to minus with the original amount of each product. So I come out with this SQL statement:

```
 public boolean updateProdQuantity(){
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    db.getConnection();
    String sql = "UPDATE sm_product SET productQuantity = " + input + "  WHERE productID = " + prodID + "";

    if (db.updateRequest(sql) == 1) {
        success = true;
    }
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

But it just update my original product amount to the amount in the cart. It never perform a minus. I wonder how should I write so my productQuantity column can minus with a variable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean something like: `SET productQuantity = productQuantity-" + input + "` ?

Comment: ya that's what I trying to do

Comment: and this doesn't work?

Comment: This one just simply update my original amount to the amount in cart. let's say I got 100 items for one product. One person bought 25. By right I should have 75 more. But my sql statement just straight away change the 100 to 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sql = "UPDATE sm_product SET productQuantity = productQuantity-" + input + "  WHERE productID = " + prodID + "";
```